# Why is the current measured through a thin film increasing with time? (experimental question)

Tags: experimental-physics, electric-circuits

I'm doing an experiment: I'm thermally evaporating a metal in a vacuum onto a quartz (very insulating) substrate, between two gold contacts that I use to measure the current through the (growing) film.

When I begin, there is no material at all between them, so I am just measuring noise/the highest sensitivity the machine can reliably measure (~1pA at 1V applied voltage). As material gets deposited, at first, none of the little "islands" of deposited material on the substrate are connected, so I see no current for some time. Then, the islands get close enough (but still not forming a connected path between the contacts!) that electrons can tunnel between them, so a small but measurable amount of current appears. As even more gets deposited, actual connected paths start appearing, and it starts [percolating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conductivity_near_the_percolation_threshold). And then, as even more gets deposited, eventually all paths are formed, and it really just starts making a thicker film.

I'm currently trying to investigate the tunneling part. So, because I'm monitoring the current across the contacts as I deposit material, I can stop the deposition when I think the current implies that I'm in the "tunneling regime". **However, even when I stop deposition, the current keeps increasing. Why?**

One reason I can guess is [electromigration.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromigration) The current makes enough material move around that it decreases the tunneling length between islands, and thus increases current. But I've done a little test: stop the deposition, and at the same time, stop the measurement (so no voltage is being applied). Wait 10 minutes or so, and start it up. If it was because of electromigration, the current should be roughly the same as where I left it. But it isn't, it seems to grow at the same rate. I also considered that my voltage/current measuring device leaves the contacts charged even after stopping the measurement, so I did the same test but shorted the contacts out right after stopping deposition and current; no difference.

The one other guess I have is that the machine vibrates a decent amount from the various pumps, and this is "shaking" the islands around enough, letting them reorder and having the same effect.

Does anyone have any suggestions for what the culprit could be, or how I could test for it?